# Interpretation of LSA results

Tags: r, latent-semantic-analysis

I perform an LSA with `textmodels_lsa` of the quanteda package in R, but I have little idea about interpreting the results.

A minimal example taken from [here](https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/lsa.html)

```r
txt <- c(d1 = "Shipment of gold damaged in a fire",
         d2 = "Delivery of silver arrived in a silver truck",
         d3 = "Shipment of gold arrived in a truck" )

mydfm <- dfm(txt)

mylsa <- textmodel_lsa(mydfm)
```

Now my questions to the return values:

- $sk are the singular values, is there a general rule of what is a high/significant singular value?
- Is it possible to choose somehow like: "dimension that explain 80% of variety"?
- are the matrices SVD of a decomposition X = SVD represented in the return?
- How can I find 2 or 3 dimensions such that patterns of documents, like clustering, emerge?
- same for dimensions. Is it possible to assign words/tokens to the dimensions to give them a topic?

Last one, how can I interpret for example the $feature matrix(rounded):

```
shipment -0.26  0.38  0.15
of       -0.42  0.07 -0.05
gold     -0.26  0.38  0.15
damaged  -0.12  0.27 -0.45
in       -0.42  0.07 -0.05
a        -0.42  0.07 -0.05
fire     -0.12  0.27 -0.45
delivery -0.16 -0.30 -0.20
silver   -0.32 -0.61 -0.40
arrived  -0.30 -0.20  0.41
truck    -0.30 -0.20  0.41
```

Does this mean, that "truck" and "arrived" are most associated with dimension 3 (highest value)? What is the difference between negative and positive values?

I tried to learn it from [here](https://www.mzes.uni-mannheim.de/socialsciencedatalab/article/advancing-text-mining/#lsa) btu was left with all these questions.